# In OpenEdge, how do you transfer parts of the data in the database in an easy way?

Tags: progress-4gl, openedge

I have a lot of data in 2 different databases and in many different tables I would like to move from one computer into a few others. The others has the same definition of the db:s. Note, not all the data should be transfered, only some that I define. Some tables fully, and some others just partly.

How would I move these data in the easiest way? To dump each table and load separately in many .d files - is not an easy way. Could you do something similar to the Incremental .df File that contains all that has to be changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dumping (and loading) entire tables is easy. You can do it from the GUI or by command line. Look at for instance [this](http://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/19227?q=dump&l=en_US&fs=Search&pn=1) KnowledgeBase entry about command line dump & load and [this](http://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/P124532?popup=true) about creating scripts for dumping the entire database.

Parts of the data is another story. This is very individual and depends on your database and your application. It's hard for a generic tool to compare data and tell if a difference in data depends on changed data, added data or deleted data. Different databases has different kinds of layout, keys and indices.

There are however several built in commands that could help you:

For instance:

`IMPORT` and `EXPORT` for importing and exporting data to files, streams etc.

**Basic import and export**

```
OUTPUT TO c:\temp\foo.data.
FOR EACH foo NO-LOCK:
  EXPORT foo.
END.
OUTPUT CLOSE.

INPUT FROM c:\temp\foo.data.
REPEAT:
  CREATE foo.
  IMPORT foo.
END.
INPUT CLOSE.
```

`BUFFER-COPY` and `BUFFER-COMPARE` for copying and comparing data between tables (and possibly even databases).

You could also use the built in commands for doing "dump" and then manually edit the created files.

**Calling Progress Built in commands**

You can call the back end that dumps data from Data Administration. That will require you to extract those .p-files from it's archives and calling them manually. This will also require you to change PROPATHS etc so it's not straightforward. You could also look into modifying the extracted files to your needs. Remember that this might break when upgrading Progress so store away your changes in separate files.

Look at this Progress KB entry: 
[Progress KB 15884](http://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/15884)

Best way for you depends on if this is a one time or reacurring task, size and layout of database etc.

Comment: So what is the code for importing foo.d? (dumped from Data Administration)
After you have done a "FOR EACH foo: DELETE foo. END."

Comment: 1) Use data administration to load data. 2) Edit the file (It contains some trailing information that starts with a . [newline] PSC etc and simply IMPORT it. 3) Write a program that uses IMPORT [table] but disregards the information in the end of the file 4) Use binary dump & load instead, it can be done by command line (PROUTIL command).

Comment: You could also look into this: http://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/P57006?q=dumpspecified&l=en_US&fs=Search&pn=1 (dumpspecified)

Comment: Also added info about calling Progress own backend for dumping data. That might be your best choice.

Comment: Did not find the archive to the Data Administration.
The output/input to files worked perfectly. Thank you!
I will now make savedata.p/loaddata.p files to export and import the data I want.